# how to pass auth in custom header

Tags: python, python-requests

I seem to be stuck in authenticating my credentials for a RESTful call with emc vplex

I am just a beginner in python, any suggestions would be helpful.

```
    import requests,json
    from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    query_headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 
    'application/json', 'auth':('username', 'password')}

    test=requests.get('https://190.xx.xx.xx/vplex/cluster-
    contexts',verify=False,headers=query_headers)
    print test
```

So when i pass in the correct credentials in auth i get output as Response [401]

,Error  401 means my authentication has failed, not sure if i am passing it correctly in the dictionary.

Comment: it should be information in documentation on server. it can be `authorization` or it has to use string `'username:password'` encoded in base64. `requests` may use argument `auth=`

Answer (score 1):

For [Basic Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) use the `auth` parameter (not in `headers`), example:

```
query_headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'}
test = requests.get(
    'https://190.xx.xx.xx/vplex/cluster-contexts', 
    auth=('username', 'password'), 
    verify=False, 
    headers=query_headers
)
```

Comment: it  did not work, maybe the application i am trying to access is not accepting this format. linux curl worked when i used os.system(). Thank you for your suggestion.